# window.open cause a SCRIPT16386: No such interface supported in ie 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have an user who have a strange error. When my script try to open a new page with `window.open("...");` I have this exception :

```
SCRIPT16386: No such interface supported
```

It look like he is the only IE 11 users who have this error, so I tough it was in his `ie 11` settings. So I turned off the Pop-up Blocker, but the error still happen.

Do you have a clue what can cause this error in IE 11 ? Thank you.

Comment: Backslashes in the URL?

Comment: I have it. I think the problem is in the client configuration...